# Как перевернуть строку в ассемблере?

Tags: ассемблер, x86, nasm

Есть строка из 10 символов, ее нужно вывести в обратном порядке интегрировав в этот код. Код выводит введённый текст,а надо в обратном. Это задание является лабой, вопросы *зачем вам эта дичь* прошу не писать.

```
section .data
  userMsg db 'Set string: '
  lenUserMsg equ $-userMsg
  dispMsg db 'You get char: '
  lenDispMsg equ $-dispMsg
  dispEnter db ' ',10
  lenDispEnter equ $-dispEnter
section .bss
  num resb 10
section .text
  global main
main:
  mov eax, 4
  mov ebx, 1
  mov ecx, userMsg
  mov edx, lenUserMsg
  int 80h

  mov eax, 3
  mov ebx, 2
  mov ecx, num
  mov edx, 10
  int 80h

  mov eax, 4
  mov ebx, 1
  mov ecx, dispMsg
  mov edx, lenDispEnter
  int 80h

  mov eax, 4
  mov ebx, 1
  mov ecx, num
  mov edx, lenDispMsg
  int 80h

  mov eax, 4
  mov ebx, 1
  mov ecx, dispEnter
  mov edx, lenDispEnter
  int 80h

  mov eax, 1
  mov ebx, 0
  int 80h
```

Comment: Со скриншота код не поправишь. И не понятно, что у Вас не получилось.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич понятно, что, не получилось перевернуть строку.

Comment: Решите сперва, **как** будете делать. Вариантов минимум три: инвертировать на месте, инвертировать при копировании в другое место, выводить по одному символу в обратном порядке. *не получилось перевернуть строку* Мы не видим ВАШИХ попыток (написанного Вами кода) перевернуть строку.

Comment: Кажется, [получилось](https://i.imgur.com/ImkRt4n.png)

Comment: @MBo, Зачетно...

Comment: Всем сорян) Просто сложно не спалившись переписать с дебиана без графики код перенести сюда)

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев используйте стек и два цикла:
цикл 1:
проходитесь по каждому символу в строке и заносите его в стек.
! не заносите в стек последний символ '\0', если он у вас присутствует.
цикл 2:
извлеките символ из стека и занесите его в исходную строку.

вуаля, готово.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Почему минусуете? Из вредности что ли?***

Я так понял есть строка DispEnter - она выводится на экран вся за раз при помощи системного перывания  80h (вызов функции 4 ядра (sys_write)). К сожалению (или к счастью) в ядре линукса нет функции выводящей строку в обратном порядке, поэтому Вам придется её инвертировать самому перед вызовом данного прерывания. Например так (нацарапано карандашом по памяти):

```
    mov  esi, dispEnter
    mov  edi, esi
    mov  ecx, 10
    cld
rep1:   
    lodsb
    push eax
    loop rep1:
    mov  ecx, 10
rep2:   
    pop  eax
    stosb
    loop rep2:
```

Comment: Я бы такую преамбулу (про отсутствие системного вызова для инвертирования строки) вообще не писал - и так понятно, что это учебное задание, и нужно реализовать инвертирование строки самостоятельно. А так вполне нормальный ответ.

Comment: Ок, учту на будущее.